# Continuous Deployment and Delivery on ECS Fargate with Circleci and Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, circleci

My goal is simple. Commit a change to the application and have it running live on AWS.

I am using Circleci and I have built all my infra with Terraform, so I want to only use Terraform to make changes to AWS. The question is, how do I update my ECS Service and keep it in sync with Terraform. The solution I came up with, not sure if I’m reinventing the wheel here, is the following:

1. Use `circleci/aws-ecr` to push the newly built image to ECR.
2. Use `circleci/aws-ecs` -> `update-task-definition-from-json` to update the `task-definition.json`
3. Since I have an updated task-definition.json in the Terraform dir holding the newly built image, it’s only a matter of a `terraform apply`. I have set it with `backend` so it should be possible to run it from circleci with circleci/terraform.
4. I should have the latest container up and running, so the first goal is achieved.
5. Now, I need to have it in sync. Circleci made changes to the `task-definition.json` and also at the terraform state. I can give an access key to my github account for the ci to commit the changes.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you showed your Circle CI config at least (ideally as an [mcve]) and also include the relevant parts of your Terraform code where possible. For our CI, I personally have a required variable of the Docker image tag (we use the commit hash to make this simple) as part of our service deploy which is passed in at run time by CI and matches the Docker image tag that has just been pushed. That way the Docker image tag is never set in infrastructure code and doesn't need updating. Without seeing what you've tried it's hard to know if that would work for you though.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the .config. 
https://github.com/Taaanos/go-REST-simple-product/blob/main/.circleci/config.yml

Comment: Another option is to let Circle CI manage the task definition completely with `aws-ecs` orb, and delete it from terraform. The way it's done know, which is not that troublesome but it's not CD too, is I get the image from ECR and change it here: https://github.com/Taaanos/go-REST-simple-product/blob/main/infrastructure/root/ecs/task-definitions/product-service.json#L3
which is not that bad.